# Can objects have instance variables declared in constructor?

Tags: java, instance-variables

### Reason why I would want this

This must be a stupid question, but I wondered about this question since sometimes when I create an object of a particular class I don't always want that object to have all of the instance variables since they are not going to be used. This makes me think if the constructor could be a good place to create instance variables for these cases where sometimes an object of a particular class should have one extra instance variable **only sometimes**. If that is even possible ofcourse. In the case beneath it would be instance variable `depth`, but in other cases it could be less trivial.

For instance in the class beneath a 2d item should differ from a 3d item by the `depth` instance variable because a 2d item does not have any depth:

```
class Box {
int width, height, depth, surface;

    public Box(int width, int height) { //2d box
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        surface = width*height;
    }

    public Box(int width, int height, int depth) { //3d box
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.depth = depth;
        surface = width*height*depth;
    }

    public getDepth() {
        return this.depth;
    }
}
```

### Questions

1. Do I use classes the wrong way here? Do you need to create a Surface class which has different subclasses for 2d boxes and 3d boxes, so that it will never occur that you have unused instance variables for an object? Is it bad practice to have unused instance variables for an object?
2. My second question is can you create an instance variable within a constructor which is not listed just beneath the class? (This sounds like a dumb thing to ask for as well as not possible at all, but sometimes I just want to be 100% sure if this is even possible).
3. In case of a 2d box getDepth() will return `0` right? The default value for an instance type int variable.

Comment: A class is, by definition, a collection of specific instance variables (and functions).  Your code above doesn't make much sense; what does a `SurfaceArea` represent?  And what does `SurfaceArea::getDepth()` mean?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried to think of a class to explain my particular problem. I should better name it box I think. Edit: I changed it to that.

Comment: Another way might be to use `Optional<Integer>`

Comment: Sounds awesome and exactly what I wanted to. I will look into that!

Comment: Here was some nice explanation about the Optional class and it's useage http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already answered all questions yourself.

1. Using a base class such as Shape which contains height and width. Then 2DShape and 3DShape which extend Shape class and define their own instance variables. Also Shape class can have abstract methods to define area, volume etc.
2. No, you cannot do that.
3. Yes, since an `int`'s value is by default `0`, it will return `0`.

Comment: Then I have one question that remains. In this case it was obvious that you could subdivide into more specific subclasses. But what if that does not make sense? Do you give each object of that class one rarely used instance variable? How bad of a style are unused instance variables?

Comment: if making subclasses does not make sense, then your design is flawed !

Comment: @Joop You can create [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).